# Extjs 4.1 Combo - Find record function fail

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

i have a combo in **http://jsfiddle.net/vTUpe/**
here is my store

```
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['id', 'name'],
        data: [{
            "id": "48",
            "name": "Alabama"
        }, {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Alaska"
        }, {
            "id": "45",
            "name": "Arizona"
        }
        //...
        ]
    });
```

but when i find index of id = 4 and id = 48 that is the same (=0). Why? how to fix that thanks

```
listeners: {
             beforeRender: function(combo) { 
                 var index4 = combo.store.find('id', '4');
                 var index48 = combo.store.find('id', '48');
                 alert(index4+"-"+index48);
             }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` matches using a regex. Use `findExact`.

Comment: that's working thank u, the same problem with findRecord function, if you know a function instead of that tell me more thanks again :)